# How to use compile-time ternary operator in C++ to get object member

Tags: c++, templates, constructor, c++14, sfinae

I have a templated class `eglue`, which determines its own n_rows and n_cols from one of the parameters passed in, which is guaranteed to have n_rows and n_cols members. The code is as follows:

```
template<typename> struct isEglueOrMat : std::false_type {};
template<typename T1, operations _op, typename T2> struct isEglueOrMat<eglue<T1, _op, T2>> : std::true_type {};
template<> struct isEglueOrMat<Matrix> : std::true_type {};

template<typename T1, operations _op, typename T2>
class eglue {
public:
    const T1& First;
    const T2& Second;
    const unsigned n_rows;
    const unsigned n_cols;
    eglue(const T1& f, const T2& s) : First(f), Second(s), n_rows(isEglueOrMat<T1>()? f.n_rows:s.n_rows), n_cols(isEglueOrMat<T1>()? f.n_cols:s.n_cols) {}
```

This doesn't work, failing with the error `request for member 'n_rows' in 'f', which is of non-class type 'const float'`, when I only want to get `n_rows` from the other item, which will be an `eglue` or `Matrix` object.

The other approach I have tried is templated constructors:

```
template<typename Dummy = void, typename Dummy2 = std::enable_if_t<isEglueOrMat<T1>(), Dummy>> eglue(const T1& f, const T2& s) : First(f), Second(s), n_rows(f.n_rows), n_cols(f.n_cols) {}
template<typename Dummy = void, typename Dummy2 = std::enable_if_t<isEglueOrMat<T2>(), Dummy>> eglue(const T1& f, const T2& s) : First(f), Second(s), n_rows(s.n_rows), n_cols(s.n_cols) {}
```

This fails with error

```
type/value mismatch at argument 1 in template parameter list for 'template<bool _Cond, class _Tp> using enable_if_t = typename std::enable_if::type'
     template<typename Dummy = void, typename Dummy2 = std::enable_if_t<isEglueOrMat<T1>(), Dummy>> eglue(const T1& f, const T2& s) : First(f), Second(s), n_rows(f.n_rows), n_cols(f.n_cols) {}
                                                                                            ^
error:   expected a constant of type 'bool', got 'isEglueOrMat<T1>()'
```

Even though I have successfully used `isEglueOrMat<type>()` at other points in the code (I will post these if necessary, but I've seen it works in other situations).

I am aware this may be a duplicate or similar to other questions, but I really haven't been able to get this to work... any advice would be much appreciated.

**EDIT:** I'm an idiot, second approach won't work anyway as you can't overload constructors with the same signature....
Is there any way to make the first approach (or any other!) work?

Comment: Is `isEglueOrMat()` `constexpr`? Otherwise it cannot be used as a template parameter.

Comment: I've used it in `template<typename T1, typename T2> 
std::enable_if_t<(isEglueOrMat<T1>() || isNumeric(T1)) && (isEglueOrMat<T2>() || isNumeric(T2)), eglue<T1, ADD, T2>> operator +(const T1& first, const T2& second) { 
    return eglue<T1, ADD, T2>(first, second); 
}`, which compiles perfectly fine... even if it isn't constexpr I don't see why it would work here and not there.

Comment: Is `isNumeric` a macro? Otherwise I don't see how you could use this expression.

Comment: Yes, I've defined it with `std::is_integral` and `std::is_floating_point`... again, this isn't the issue. :/

Comment: What are  you trying to instantiate exactly? `eglue<float, ..., float>`? It is not clear what are the possible "types" for `T1` / `T2`...

Comment: `eglue` will always have at least one of `T1` or `T2` as another `eglue` or `Matrix`, so either `First` or `Second` will always have `n_rows` and `n_cols` members. An example would be `eglue<Matrix, (operation), float>` or `eglue<eglue<...>, (operation), Matrix>` - they may be nested.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use tag dispatching with delegating constructor:

```
template<typename T1, operations _op, typename T2>
class eglue {
public:
    const T1& First;
    const T2& Second;
    const unsigned n_rows;
    const unsigned n_cols;
    eglue(const T1& f, const T2& s) : eglue(f,s,isEglueOrMat<T1>()) {}
private:
    eglue(const T1& f, const T2& s, std::true_type)  : First(f), Second(s), n_rows(f.n_rows), n_cols(f.n_cols) {}
    eglue(const T1& f, const T2& s, std::false_type) : First(f), Second(s), n_rows(s.n_rows), n_cols(s.n_cols) {}
};
```

Or second approach, make sure to depend **indirectly** on `T1`:

```
template<typename T1, operations _op, typename T2>
class eglue {
public:
    const T1& First;
    const T2& Second;
    const unsigned n_rows;
    const unsigned n_cols;
    template <typename _T1 = T1, std::enable_if_t<isEglueOrMat<_T1>{}, bool> = true>
    eglue(const T1& f, const T2& s)  : First(f), Second(s), n_rows(f.n_rows), n_cols(f.n_cols) {}
    template <typename _T1 = T1, std::enable_if_t<!isEglueOrMat<_T1>{}, bool> = false>
    eglue(const T1& f, const T2& s)  : First(f), Second(s), n_rows(s.n_rows), n_cols(s.n_cols) {}
};
```

Answer (score -1):

For the second approach to work, you should use `isEglueOrMat<T>::value` as a bool constant. When you use `isEglueOrMat<T>()` it is treated as an object of type `integral_constant`, a structure. When you used it in a other Boolean expressions, it was silently coerced to bool (`std::integral_constant` does provide such an operator). Another option, is to explicitly cast it to bool, 
`static_cast<bool>(isEglueOrMat<T>())` works too, as does C-style cast.

The first approach can be made viable too, but it requires more indirection (plain standard operator won't work as you see) and some, at first glance tricky, SFINAE play.

Comment: I don't think you can declare structs `constexpr`? Or am I missing something?

Comment: Oh, it's a struct, sorry, I've missed it. Editing the post.

Comment: Your answer does not make sense *"When you used it in a other Boolean expressions, it was silently coerced to bool."*, that's exactly what you want...